# Problem with responsive @media queries resize between developer tool and browser window

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries, developer-tools

I'm using different media queries to resize the style of my css based on the *device-width*,
I did the mistake to work on the website almost all the time looking at that in developer mode, changing the device size with the responsive dimensions, and in developer mode everything works fine.

But when im not in developer mode and I resize the window, of the browser, manually, the css keep being on the */*large screen*/* style and is not responsive.
The media queries should understand that im resizin the window n it get less than certain width no?

those r my queries:

```
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 767px) 
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 991px) 
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 992px) and (max-device-width: 1199px) 
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px)
```

responsive working on developer mode

[image: responsive working on developer mode]

Resposive not working on browser while manually resize the window

[image: Resposive not working on browser while manually resize the window]

Comment: Also tried to change from 'max-device-width' to 'max-width'

Comment: We can't debug screenshots. Does your page contain the minimum requirement for media queries to work properly - a `viewport` meta element?

Comment: I see, I'v put the screenshots there to actually show whats appening visually, as code i gave u which @media queries im using, im self learning and not english native, what do u mean with minimum requirment? Cause as u can see in the developer mode the media queries are working so, i believe i have the requirment, if u mean like this i have this on my <head> :
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem, where I had to add something to the head tag of the code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Adding this fixed my media query responsiveness.

Comment: i already have this:
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
in my <head> elements, i didn't put it on the snippet cause i didn't know was related